# Using Task.Unwrap to get to the inner task

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I'm trying to access the inner task with `Task.Unwrap` and I'm getting this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult]' 
to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Boolean]'.
```

To reproduce the problem:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        tcs.SetResult(true);
        Task task1 = tcs.Task;

        Task<Task> task2 = task1.ContinueWith(
            (t) => t, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

        Task task3 = task2.Unwrap();

        try
        {
            Task<bool> task4 = (Task<bool>)task3;

            Console.WriteLine(task4.Result.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

In the real project, I'm provided with a list of `Task<Task>`, where each inner task is a generic task. Can I not use `Unwrap` to access the inner tasks and their results?

Comment: Why do you have `Task<Task>`? Can't you change that to `Task<Task<bool>>`?

Comment: @svick, that's what a method of my library accepts. It's a list of tasks, each task wraps another task. The list can contain `Task<Task<bool>>`, `Task<Task<object>>`, `Task<Task<string>>`, as well as simply `Task<Task>`. I don't have control over this, and I need to figure out the type of nested task during runtime. It appears, I can't use the standard `Unwrap` for this, and have to come up with my own version, based on `ContinueWith`, I suppose. Which should not be a problem, but I'm just trying to understand why `Task.Unwrap` works this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using `ContinueWith()`, which will cast the inner `Task` to `Task<YourType>`, followed by `Unwrap()`:

```
Task<bool> task4 = task2.ContinueWith(t => (Task<bool>)t.Result).Unwrap();
```

Comment: I guess we cannot make it universal, so it doesn't depend on the generic type, can we?

Comment: Somehing `like task4 = (Task<bool>)task2.ContinueWith(t => t.Result).Unwrap()` ...

Comment: @avo How is that any better?

Comment: I wanted to `Unwrap` them all first with `list.Select`, to use as a part of a larger set with `ContinueWhenAll`. Then I would cast the results.

Comment: I think the problem is that `Task<T>` is not covariant, so is not the `Unwrap`.

Comment: @avo Covariance wouldn't help you here. I think that doing exactly what you want is impossible: when you have `Task<Task>`, then there is no way to find out what is the real type of the inner `Task` without waiting for the outer `Task`. But you want to get a `Task` of the right type immediately.